# Master Aggregator is not running - Memsql

Tags: cluster-computing, nodes, singlestore

I have been using memsql community edition for last 3 months, suddenly it stopped working.

Here is the result it shows on memsql-ops.

[image]

I have tried the following command, but it did not have any effect.

```
AGGREGATOR SET AS MASTER;
```

**Question** : How to make it up and running?

Comment: Try to run `memsql-ops memsql-start --all`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution with the following command,

```
memsql-ops cluster-start
```

Comment: I encountered the same issue today and executed this answer without knowing it was you.. :D and it worked! thanks